# Product of minimal polynomials of restriction to invariant subspaces equals the minimal polynomial of the vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, minimal-polynomials

I have been reading Schaum's outlines Linear Algebra and this was a motivating result to prove the primary decomposition theorem.
Statement of Theorem 10.8:
[image]

Its proof as in my textbook:
[image]

I got stuck in the fourth line which says

> $g(T_1)=0$ and $h(T_2)=0$ because $U=Ker[g(T)]$ and $W=Ker[h(T)]$

I don't know how this argument works. An explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that $T_i$ is the *restriction* of $T$:
If $u\in U=\ker g(T)$, then $g(T_1)u=g(T|_U)u=g(T)u=0$.

Comment: Okay so this resticted operator works as a zero operator on the invariant space. $U$.   I got it, thanks!